# SQL, select years before, but not after

Tags: mysql, sql

OK I have a table with project numbers & clients.
The project numbers a based on the years. E.G.

- 2017001
- 2017002
- 2017003

I want to select all the clients before a given year, but not if they also have a project number after that given year.

So the table would look something like this:

- 2017001: Client A
- 2017002: Client B
- 2017003: Client C
- 2016001: Client C
- 2016002: Client D
- 2016003: Client F
- 2015001: Client C
- 2015002: Client D
- 2015003: Client F

If I wanted to select all client 2016 & before, I'd get Clients D & F, but not C, since it's also in 2017.

I know I can select all per-2016 clients & then do a loop on each of them to check if they have a project number in 2017, but is there an easier way to do this in a single SQL statement?

My current statement looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobno < 2016000
```

I know this doesn't work, but I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobno < 2016000 AND jobno !> 2016000
```

Comment: What is the column type, is it varchar or number??
Secondly, you want D and F as output, right?

Comment: My co-worker suggested this & it seems to be working for me:

    SELECT DISTINCT client from jobs WHERE jobno < 2017000 AND client not in (SELECT DISTINCT client from jobs WHERE jobno > 2017000)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobno < 2017000
```

Comment: This will not properly eliminate Client C from the example test.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to select all client 2016 & before, you need the query `jobno < 2017000`, not `jobno < 2016000`

First go by selecting with the query `jobno < 2017000` and save the result.

```
INSERT INTO result SELECT DISTINCT * FROM jobs WHERE jobno < 2017000
```

then do another select from the saved result, `jobno !> 2017000`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM result WHERE jobno !> 2017000
```

final result will be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So first `SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobno < 2016000` will select jobs where job number is strictly inferior to 2016000, which means you actually exclude jobs in 2016.

Instead, use :

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobno < 2017000
```

Now if you also want to exclude clients who have jobs in 2017, this should work :

```
SELECT clientname
FROM jobs
GROUP BY clientname
HAVING max(jobno) < 2017000
```

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. What is the "max_jobno" doing? It doesn't seem like it's being used.